# Как побороть ошибку при обновлении с Ubuntu 15.10 на 16.04?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Идет нормально процесс обновления, доходит до phpmyadmin, а дальше все на прикрепленных скринах. Почему ошибка, не могу понять, подскажите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в тексте (на второй картинке), вроде бы, написано, что можно сделать дальше.

Answer (score 1):

Теперь в конфигурационном файле /etc/mysql/my.cnf нельзя задавать пустую директиву `port`, также нельзя указывать параметр `--port` без значения. Раньше предполагалось, что если вы не указываете порт, то подразумеваете 3306, теперь его следует прописать явно

```
[mysqld]
...
port = 3306
```

Однако, в вашем случае от этой директивы вообще следует избавиться, так как у вас соединение устанавливается через сокет и сетевой порт вообще не требуется. Посмотрите конфигурационный файл /etc/mysql/my.cnf и удалите от туда директиву `port`.